# First post review audit had an answer with a missing user box

Tags: bug

I had this "first answer" to review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20991031

The magic audit code that's supposed to hide the details of established users gave me this user information box (is there a proper name for these things?)

---

[image]

---

which immediately made me suspect that something was amiss, which was confirmed when I visited the question. It is probably not what's wanted with a review audit.

Comment: Same happened with me for https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26271936.